# perform segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i was working on this app and it has been working really well and then i tried to run the app and didn't get why a segue didn't run as it is always suppose to do when the app opens. i then pressed a button that performs the same segue and the app would crash.

here is the error message:

```
2014-04-04 16:30:54.733 On Tour Company[3854:60b] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

2014-04-04 16:30:55.043 On Tour Company[3854:60b] Current user: (null)

2014-04-04 16:30:55.246 On Tour Company[3854:60b] Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.

2014-04-04 16:31:00.593 On Tour Company[3854:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LoginViewController 0x9bad0e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key barSignUp.'

*** First throw call stack:

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02af11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023b48e5 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b80fe1 -[NSException raise] + 17

3   Foundation                          0x02074d9e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282

4   Foundation                          0x01fe11d7 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88

5   Foundation                          0x01fe0731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267

6   Foundation                          0x02042b0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412

7   UIKit                               0x0132b1f4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106

8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023c67de -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62

9   CoreFoundation                      0x02aec76a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314

10  UIKit                               0x01329d4d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417

11  UIKit                               0x015d88bd -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 220

12  UIKit                               0x015d8eb6 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 88

13  UIKit                               0x0119541c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72

14  On Tour Company                     0x000076bf -[BlogTableViewController logout:] + 143

15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023c6880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77

16  UIKit                               0x010763b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108

17  UIKit                               0x013638df -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139

18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023c6880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77

19  UIKit                               0x010763b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108

20  UIKit                               0x01076345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61

21  UIKit                               0x01177bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66

22  UIKit                               0x01177fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577

23  UIKit                               0x01177243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641

24  UIKit                               0x010b5ddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852

25  UIKit                               0x010b69d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117

26  UIKit                               0x010885f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242

27  UIKit                               0x01072353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455

28  CoreFoundation                      0x02a7a77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15

29  CoreFoundation                      0x02a7a10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235

30  CoreFoundation                      0x02a971ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910

31  CoreFoundation                      0x02a969d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467

32  CoreFoundation                      0x02a967eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

33  GraphicsServices                    0x02a1a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192

34  GraphicsServices                    0x02a1a42b GSEventRun + 104

35  UIKit                               0x01074f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225

36  On Tour Company                     0x0000316d main + 141

37  libdyld.dylib                       0x03642701 start + 1

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

here is the code for the the first view controller in this set. in the view under view will load (using parse backend) i check who is logged into the app and if no one is it suppose to go to the log in screen. I dont know why it isn't.

```
#import "BlogTableViewController.h"

@interface BlogTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BlogTableViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if ([currentUser  isEqual: @"nil"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showLogin" sender: self];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
 forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}




- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
[PFUser logOut];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showLogin" sender: self];

}
@end
```

and here just incase it helps is the code of the segue goes to. most of the code is related to logging in a user with a parse backend but here it is.

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Hello");
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[self.usernameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.passwordField resignFirstResponder];
}



- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
NSString *username = self.usernameField.text;
NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Make sure you enter a username and password!"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertView show];
}
else{
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else{
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
        }];
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your outlets in Interface Builder. It looks like the `barSignUp` outlet is wrongly connected.

Comment: now my question for you is how are you suppose to set up a bar button. i know i need to use a push segue since i am using a navigation bar but should the segue go from the bar button to the next screen or another way. in basic terms how do is set it up.

Comment: @user3499627, create a new question with your new problem so more people can see it and answer. And please accept this answer if it helped.